# Change Google account name

Tags: google-account, google-account-profile

How to change Google account name?

I was trying to find answer with Google, but got many not actual information since Google has done many changes in its user interface.

Comment: Are you referring to what’s in front of `@gmail.com`?

Comment: No, I don't need to change e-mail, I need to change just surname

Comment: For me, it’s in the Google+ profile (click on name). Unfortunately, I don’t have a non-G+ account, so I don’t know where else it would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Editing your profile name in Google+ will change your name in all the
>   Google products you use for this account.

1. Go to your Google+ profile page
2. Click on your name
3. Change your name

[More on create or change your Google+ profile name](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1228271?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

You can chage your Nick Name and other personal info. for this go to this link:

https://myaccount.google.com/privacy?pli=1#personalinfo